# python tkinter package tk.call eval

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl

I'm using python tkinter to run tcl in python
And there are two ways to run a tcl command:

```
import tkinter 
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.eval("winfo exists .l0")
root.tk.call("winfo exists .l0")
```

They have the same meaning

But what's different?
And if I haven't define a widget names .l0
and can I directly use

```
child = ".l0"
child.winfo_exists()
```

?
Because python told me "str has no attribute winfo_exists"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `call` passes each argument to tcl as a separate word, where `eval` will evaluate a string by first parsing it and then executing it.

In other words, this:

```
root.eval("winfo exists .l0")
```

... is functionally identical to this:

```
root.tk.call("winfo", "exists", ".l0")
```

As for the error message `'str' object has no attribute 'winfo_exists'`, it means exactly that. `"l0"` is the name of an object in the embedded tcl interpreter, but in python `"l0"` is just a string and python strings don't have the attribute `winfo_exists`.

Comment: if I need to test a window named .l0 without type of it, do you know how to deal with that?

Comment: @shuji: I don't understand your question. ".l0" doesn't have a type in the world of tcl. In tcl, everything is a string. I'm sure that what you want can be done, but I can't understand what you want.

Comment: what I mean is that, in wish(tcl shell), I can type "winfo exists .l0" but how can I do that in python? With .l0 an unknown widget(not a topleve, frame etc.)

Comment: @shuji: Like my answer shows, you can call `root.tk.call` and pass in whatever window name you want. That will only tell you if there is a tcl/tk window by that name, it won't tell you if a tkinter object representing that widget exists. This is a highly unusual thing to do, since with tkinter you almost never know the internal window name.